# Adding custom dropdown control to ABP framework in Identity User form

Tags: enums, abp

I would like to display a custom dropdown(Notification levels in numeric) in the Identity User form in ABP Framework.
1,2,3,4,5 in the dropdown.
So when I used the enum, I am able to display only as One,Two,Three,Four,Five.

I created an enum and in ConfigureExtraProperties method in the ExtensionConfigurator I added user.AddOrUpdateProperty to load the dropdown